# Is PyBluez alive?

Tags: python, bluetooth

The PyBluez project seems to be the canonical project for doing Bluetooth in Python (Please correct me if I'm wrong). However, last version is 0.18 from Nov 2009). Issues (currently, I'm most annoyed by issue 43: no support for python 2.7) aren't being fixed.

I do see some activity though, so I wonder its state. Is PyBluez the canonical way to do Bluetooth? Is there an alternative to PyBluez? (I'm alost missing BlueSoleil stack support).

Comment: Try the alternative binaries at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez

Comment: Thank you @cgohlke, binaries (at least 32 bit) working very well.

Comment: @gohlke - just wanted to say thanks for the great work you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is new version of pybluez 0.20
works with python 2.7 and 3.3
https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/downloads/list

Comment: how about 64 bits binaries? Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 1):

There are alternative binaries here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez

The mailing list appears to not be completely dead: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pybluez

Answer (score 0):

It's alive,the source code is update recently https://github.com/karulis/pybluez